# Проблема с настройкой сервера, долгая задержка

Tags: apache, nginx

есть сервер nginx+apache+php.
Проблема в чём, долго генерируется ответ(200) на запрос к статике.
Если я делаю запрос к картинке с включённым кешем браузера(Chrome "Disable cache"="off"), то получаю ответ 304 и TTFB равен примерно 50мс (45мс - пинг к серверу). Если я отключаю кеш ("Disable cache"="on") то ответ 200 и TTFB равен примерно 100мс (тоисть примерно 50мс оно типа ищет картинку, или чем-то другим занято  (сервер на SSD)). Где мне копать проблему, какие настройки нужно глянуть? всётаки 50мс это много потерь для статики.

в .htaccess есть такая настройка для картинок, но не думаю что она влияет

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png$ /images/thumbnail_images/noimage.png [L]
```

Comment: Как настроена связка Apache и Nginx, если она действительно есть?

Comment: я точно не могу сказать, так как не имею прямого доступа к серверу, знаю что Nginx через себя всё пропускает(в заголовках ответов написано "server: nginx"), насколько я знаю,  Nginx  ничего не кеширует, тоисть тупо перенаправляет на Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx буферизует все ответы от Apache в памяти. Это уже само по себе добавляет задержку.

В дополнении к этому, если размер статики больше чем заданный размер буферов ([`proxy_buffers`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers)), Nginx будет сохранять часть ответов во временных файлах, вызывая дополнительную нагрузку на подсистему I/O, и соответветственно бОльшее значение TTFB.

Вы можете:

- отключить буферизацию в Nginx (`proxy_buffering off;`). Однако это повлечёт за собой бОльшую нагрузку на CPU. Дополнительным моментом является то, что даже при выключенной буферизации Nginx всегда будет буферизировать заголовки HTTP ответа
- выделить статические файлы для обслуживания Nginx-ом напрямую с файловой системы, минуя Apache (см. ниже). Это лучшее решениe, если всё находится на одном сервере. Nginx - полноценный веб-сервер. Ему не нужно ничего проксировать, если он имеет доступ к нужным файлам
- оптимизировать связку Nginx->Apache, добавив к ней парамер `keepalive`
- где-бы не происходило gzip сжатие, оно добавит дополнительный overhead к времени ответа. Произведите заранее максимальное сжатие файлов, поддающихся компрессии, и используйте gzip static модуль Nginx

```
server {
    # добавить root, если отсуствует, дабы Nginx знал местонахождение файлов
    root /var/www/html;
    # если у вас действительно проскируются все ответы, уже есть что-то наподобие данного блока (его можно оставить как есть):
    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

# примвер выделения location для статики
location ~\.jpg$ {
    # Выделено пустое location чтобы proxy_pass не был применен
    # здесь удобно добавить директивы для статики, например expires max;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, будем смотреть, если есть ещё какие-то места тормозов, пишите